# Do batch norm makes sense for regression problems?

Tags: regression, batch-normalization

When my network is performing regression (like DQN) it makes sense to use batchnorm in network when output of my network should vary from [0, 100000]?

one way to tackle it is to normalize output but output is used for ranking choices in RL system so scaling can lead to small numerical errors that can explode after upscaling...

Comment: Use boosting methods :)

Comment: I don't see benefit of boosting methods there especially for RL problem where you have to develop performan algorithm for decision making

Comment: Well I am sorry, little to no knowledge on RL